# Switching branches in Git doesn't remove directories

Tags: git

I've created two branches in Git:

```
git branch F1
git branch F2
```

Next, I switch over to F1:

```
git checkout F1
```

I *rename* my `UnitTests` directory to `Tests`:

```
git mv .\UnitTests .\Tests
git commit . -m "Moving unit tests to Tests directory"
```

At this point, I have a `master` branch with a `UnitTests` directory, an F2 branch with a `UnitTests` directory and a `F1` branch with a `Tests` directory.  So, I switch over to `F2`:

```
git checkout F2
```

When I do this, I now see the `UnitTests` directory added back, but I also see the `Tests` directory (From the F1 branch) still there.  It even has all the same files.

I can *force* it to be removed by running:

```
git clean -fd
```

However, I'm wondering why remnants from the old branch are lingering around.  I've looked at a few other potential duplicates, but all of them note cases where my *move* was not yet committed.  I clearly committed the move to F1 before switching branches.

Any ideas?  I'm running `git version 1.9.2.msysgit.0` on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have files or directories (could be empty) that git ignore (hidden or explicit ignored) in the `UnitTests` directory

Therefore, git wouldn't delete these files so he keeps them in the directory.

Comment: Hmm I will confirm this.  Is there some default ignore list?  I ran `git init` right before, and copied over some files from a Subversion enlistment.

Comment: check if there are hidden files or if you have a global `.gitignore` file or a specific one in the repository

Comment: No hidden files.  But it doesn't repro if I just create a single text file.  Right now, it's looking like Git will ignore `bin` and `obj` folders by default.  This is a fresh Git install and a fresh `git init`.

Comment: you can check if it ignore files using `git check-ignore UnitTests`

Comment: I also don't have a `.gitignore` file anywhere (in the repo or in my user profile directory)

Comment: Also, no hidden files in the entire directory structure except the `.git` directory.

Comment: Figured it out!  No hidden or ignored files, just several dozen *empty* directories which basically act as if they were ignored, without showing up in the `check-ignore` list.  Thanks!  `+1`

Answer (score 3):

I believe the other answers are *mostly* correct, but not quite.  Figured I would add my own answer in case it helps any other Git newbies.

First off, I checked for ignore rules and for hidden files, but none of either turned up.

What is getting left behind in `Tests` when I switch over to `F2` is *empty* directories.  They're not ignored or hidden or anything, they were just never checked in due to being empty.  It seems the `checkout` command will remove all the versioned files, but leave the empty directories alone.  The `clean` command will clean these up.

Looks like Git is working as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm laughing, because you're right. I actually contradicted myself mentioning "ignored directories" and then saying git doesn't care about directories. Since git doesn't care about directories, it won't remove them (and you can't add them to the repository). Obviously "ignored directories" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a new directory with one file inside.

I'm guessing you had maybe some hidden or ignored files (or subdirectories) in the test directory.

Git doesn't care about directories - only about content inside them, so renaming a directory is pretty much the same as "renaming" the files inside.

This is why you can't `git add` on an empty directory - and it doesn't show up in `git status`.

A good way to check is: `git clean -ndx` (shows both ignored files and empty directories).